# How to use paypal in corona sdk?

Tags: sdk, paypal, coronasdk

**How to use paypal in corona sdk?**

```
In my app i have book items i couldn't use of inapp so i deceid to use paypal i did'nt know how to process paypal in corona sdk ...help me
```

Comment: I dont think that, appstore or android market would allow such thing in an application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Corona doesn't have a plugin for PayPal available yet, you would have to show a web popup rather than apple's one-click in-app purchases and would be slightly more complicated for the customer but that's the best you have until a PayPal plugin is made available. For more information regarding PayPal integration check out: http://jonbee.be/post/1208865269/on-implementing-in-app-purchase-using-the-corona-sdk

-- Moksh